# LogonFailure when starting programs via local service

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to start programs inside a .NET service (installed and running under "local service" account on a Win2012 machine).

As long as we do not try to change the user context, everything is fine, but if the ProcessStartInfo instance is provided with a username, domain and password we are getting the following message when calling Process.Start:

"Logon failure: the user has not been granted requested logon type at this computer"

In the event log I have seen that the failure refers to a logon type 2, which is the code for "interactive".

I thought I could assign that right via "local security policy", but there is only a right "log on as a service" and one "log on as a batch job", not one specifically for "log on as interactive".

The second thing I checked was wether it was possible to change the logon type to something I can assign to the technical user ( 5 -"logon as a service" in this case) when starting programs.

I do know that the logon type is something I provide when doing things like impersonation, but I do not see any possibility to set the logon type for ProcessStartInfo instances, there is no property for it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user you are using does not have the rights to log on locally to the computer. Go to '**Administrative Tools**' and double click on '**Local Security Policy**'.

Select and expand the '**Local Policies**' and select '**User Rights Assignment**'. On the right pane there is the policy '**Allow Log On Locally**' which you must add the user that requires access.